# The four-member family buys lottery tickets at one a piece. How many favorable outcomes are there if there are 100 participants?

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose 100 people, including the 4-member Roy family, buy lottery tickets (one a piece). Three winning tickets will be drawn (without replacement) from a bag. How many outcomes will make the Roy family happy?

Can someone help me with this problem? I cannot think of anything suitable related to this.

Comment: Happy presumably means the family gets at least one winning ticket, yes?

Comment: In any case, "how many outcomes" is has no absolute meaning without more context. A better question is: What is the _probability_ that the Roy family gets at least one winning ticket?

Comment: @quasi:  there are $100 \cdot 99 \cdot 98$ total outcomes assuming the order of tickets means different prizes and matters.  It makes sense to ask how many of these result in one of four given tickets being drawn.  The probability is the ratio of these.

Comment: I am very appalled at the framing of the question , this is from a previous university question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that the Roy family gets no winning tickets is
$${q=\left(\frac{97}{100}\right)\left(\frac{96}{99}\right)\left(\frac{95}{98}\right)\left(\frac{94}{97}\right)}
=\frac{7144}{8085}\approx.8836116265
$$
hence the probability that the Roy family gets at least one winning ticket is
$$p = 1-q = 1-\frac{7144}{8085}=\frac{941}{8085} \approx .1163883735$$

Explanation:

Name the members of the Roy family as A,B,C,D.

For the Roy family to get no winning tickets

- A must get a losing ticket: $97$ losing tickets out of $100$ tickets.

  B must also get a losing ticket: $96$ losing tickets left out of $99$ remaining tickets (i.e., all tickets other than the one selected by A).

  C must also get a losing ticket: $95$ losing tickets left out of $98$ remaining tickets (i.e., all tickets other than the ones selected by A,B).

  D must also get a losing ticket: $94$ losing tickets left out of $97$ remaining tickets (i.e., all tickets other than the ones selected by A,B,C).

Comment: Thanks a lot , the framing of the question apparently made it tough for me to comprehend .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: there are $100 \cdot 99 \cdot 98$ total outcomes assuming the order of tickets means different prizes and matters.  How many of these have at least one of the family's tickets drawn?  It is easier to compute how many of these do not have any of the family's tickets drawn and subtract.